# horizonalscrollview to many images?

Tags: android

sorry I'm really new at this, hopefully I posted in the right place.

I'm trying to make an app to change my wallpaper, but i'm stuck. If I add more than about seven images to my xml the app just closes itself. My images are 960x854. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these threads:

[Android - how to improve HorizontalScrollView that has lots of views/images inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195821/android-how-to-improve-horizontalscrollview-that-has-lots-of-views-images-insid)

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/816292b2970f2ccd?pli=1

It would seem that you're running out of memory. Using [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) instead of a HorizontalScrollView would be a more memory efficient way of handling what you're trying to do as it doesn't have to hold all images in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I have been trying to implement a gallery in place of my horizontalscrollview, but am having some trouble. Do you know any good tutorials or hint on a way to do it? Oh and, thanks for the link to the widget. it got me started.

Comment: So I forgot to add smaller images to the drawable-ldpi folder. Everything is good now.